# Request module wait for document ready

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I'm doing web scraping. Actually I use [request module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) in node, modern sites are using the newer frameworks like Angular, EmberJS and generate html. When I load the page with request the document is not ready, so I get just the javascript code and not the HTML code.

Is possible to generate a timeout and then load the page?

Answer (score 0):

The `request` module is just an HTTP client, it will only get you the text returned from a particular URL. A straightforward way to achieve what you are trying to do would be to open a URL with a headless browser like PhantomJS (https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node) and actually execute the page before evaluating its content.

Comment: but Panthomjs is not a library for nodejs

Comment: The link in my answer is to a library for node that provides bindings to PhantomJS, so that you can interact with an executing page from node to retrieve the content.

Comment: Ok Thanks, I'll try with that